# Can slightly lowered encryption standards remain secure?

Tags: encryption

State security agencies argue that lower encryption standards, but "secure enough" to resist mundane, everyday interception, would allow security agencies to defend against terrorist attacks.

- Would such a lower encryption standard exist in such a form that the bad actors would be unaware of the lower encryption yet keep "regular people" secure?
- Would such encryption be resistant to interception by bad actors? Could we trust it? If so how?
- What would prevent bad actors from implementing their own, stronger encryption?

For the record, I am interested in the technical reasoning behind the strategy and whether as an engineering approach it is sound at achieving the goal of reasonable privacy alongside security. I'm not interested in subjective, editorial based discussion around civil liberties/privacy.

Comment: Are they arguing for lowered encryption strength, or simply to maintain backdoors or known keys? This is an important distinction.

Comment: @Doug: name/link to  your source, please.

Comment: Can I assume we're talking about a hypothetical world (which may or may not match the real one, for all we know) where state security agencies definitely do foil terrorist attacks, and don't use the data for anything else?

Comment: @immibis please read the OP's last line.

Comment: I consider this question as too broad and lots of it would be opinion based too. Apart from that there is lots of public discussion about the topic (like why terrorists would use weak encryption if better is available etc). And see also the problems the last attempts to weaken public crypto caused, like [FREAK attack](https://freakattack.com/).

Comment: @steffen it may appear broad cause I'm a security newb and trying to make sense of articles like http://news.yahoo.com/following-paris-attacks--encryption-services-face-new-scrutiny-154300219.html

Comment: @DougT. in the article you link, the only mention of the technical controls is this: "FBI, CIA and NSA to call for companies to build “backdoors” or trusted man-in-the-middle surveillance into encrypted communications". This appears to not be a "lowering of encryption standard".

Answer (score 4):

Cryptographic tools don't age out in the same way cars do: they don't lose a small percentage of their strength each year (actually, they do as computers become more powerful, more on that later *). Often, a critical vulnerability is found in the algorithm, or its popular implementation, drastically reducing the attack effort.

For example, brute forcing TLS chipters would take ages, but Heartbleed attack allows you to reveal private keys withing minutes. Anyone with a computer can exploit this bug, not only security agencies.

Similarly, SHA-1 is not broken (yet), but for a very similar algorithm, SHA-0, collisions can be found within hours on consumer hardware. Should this attack be extended to SHA-1, it will be instantly and hopelessy broken. That's the whole reason it is being phased out now, before that happens.

So in practice it's very hard to find "lowered encryption standards" which are still secure enough to protect from common criminals.

*) A good example of a cryptographic algorithm which has actually aged out peacefully is [DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard#Security_and_cryptanalysis). To this day, brute force attack remains the practical option, however, computers have made such tremendous progress since the 1970s that such attack can be performed in less than 1 day on top modern hardware. DES is used to this day in form of [Triple DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES), which is somewhat unefficient (requires 3 times the effort to encrypt/decrypt but only 2 times the effective key size) but still quite secure.

Answer (score 1):

1. Good encryption standards are open knowledge. They are attacked by as many people as possible to bring as many different techniques to bear against them, and to allow for any inconsistencies in implementations to be picked up. Bad actors are really good at this analysis. If there is a weakness, it has to be assumed that they will find it, given sufficient time. The problem is that there is no sensible way to determine whether they have found this weakness or not. Consider the use of Ultra data during WW2 - there were occasions where attacks were allowed to go ahead in order to hide the information that the British and Americans could read German transmissions using Enigma. These were purely to keep the Germans thinking that their encryption method was secure. There is nothing to prevent similar happening if a weakness in an encryption method was found by bad actors. You would know for certain that the "good guys" could read your data, but have absolutely no idea if the "bad guys" could, which seems less than ideal.
2. This isn't really a property of an encryption method. If you have a perfect one time pad, and send the encrypted text over plain text email, anyone could intercept it. Doesn't really matter though, since they still can't read it without the correct pad. They wouldn't be able to *modify* the message undetectably - anyone with the correct pad would decrypt and find gibberish, unless the attackers were very lucky. In general, it is a good property of an encryption method that an attacker can have your message, the algorithm, and as much computing power as they like, and it should still be infeasible to decrypt the message without the key. For a backdoored encryption method, this is not the case - there is a second key. Assuming it is used in the same way as the original key (which would be an odd, but potentially possible design), you've doubled the chances of someone finding a key. And if that key is fixed for all messages, it wouldn't be long before someone starts encrypting short messages using the backdoored encryption and attempting to break them with other keys. For a weakened encryption method, the availability of computing power is the problem - if you can run through possible keys fast enough for security services to break messages usefully, there is nothing to stop attackers doing exactly the same.
3. Nothing. You could legislate against it, but the key thing about "bad guys" is that they tend not to care so much about the law. Furthermore, we already have better encryption. We have methods that are effectively unbreakable in reasonable timespans. They are available on millions of devices already. You also run across the problem of international boundaries. All it would take is one country that doesn't actively crack down on possession of "unbreakable" encryption, and your plan is broken.

   Essentially, any such plan would be asking people to change from existing encryption methods built into their devices to use new, relatively untested ones. Law abiding people might do this. Lazy people probably won't unless it is enforced - but bear in mind that this level of encryption is available in old devices that are sitting in drawers, forgotten about, devices that the manufacturers no longer exist for, and in home made devices. Criminals get the easy ride - do nothing, and assume that the security forces can't get them all. They appear to be sending lots of random data? It's compressed files. Look, we can decompress them to reveal valid data.